# nested models add and destroy through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have form with fields for nested model, it looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:partners, @car], url: wizard_path do |f|
  = f.association :payment_types, as: :check_boxes
  = f.simple_fields_for :prices do |p|
    = p.input :from_days
    = p.input :to_days
    = p.input :netto_price
    = p.input :available_from, as: :string
    = p.input :available_to, as: :string 
  = f.submit
```

Now I want to have button "Add new" and when I click it  it will render through javascript fields for new Price. How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the form in a partial
2. make a button `<%= link_to new_wizard_path, remote: true %>`
3. create a file in your views/wizards folder `new.js.erb`
4. In `new.js.erb`, do a javascript call to remove the old form re-render the form partial. I would do this with jQuery:

   $('#form-div').html('<%= render 'form %>');

And there you have an Ajax thing. Simple as that.